Is it decidable if noncommutative polynomial ideal is homogeneous?
Hi everyone and thanks in advance already for any help!
I am currently wondering about the following problem:
Given $f_1, \dots,f_r \in K\langle X\rangle$, where $K$ is a field, $X$ is a finite set of indeterminates, and $K\langle X \rangle$ denotes the free algebra of $X$ over $K$.
Is it decidable whether the two-sided ideal $I = \langle f_1,\dots,f_r \rangle$ is homogeneous?
What I have so far is the following thought: Write each $f_i$ in terms of its homogeneous components, i.e., $f_i = \sum_j^{d_i} g_{i,j}$ with $g_{i,j} \in K\langle X\rangle$ homogeneous. Then, consider the ideal $J = \langle g_{i,j} \mid i = 1,\dots,r, j = 1,\dots,d_i\rangle$. Now, $I$ is homogeneous if and only if $I = J$.
This shows that the corresponding commutative problem, i.e., when $f_1,\dots,f_r \in K[X]$, is decidable (because we can use Gröbner bases to verify whether $I = J$).
However, checking equality of ideals is not decidable in the free algebra in general (since the ideal membership problem is not decidable in general in the free algebra). The question is, does the special structure of the ideal $J$ and its relation to $I$ help here in any way? Or, the other way round, can we encode an arbitrary ideal membership problem as a question about an ideal being homogeneous (this would show that the latter problem is undecidable)?
